# Extending TabControl and TabItem, how to handle click event on TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to write a custom TabControl, to change the complete look and behavior of it. The idea is that it is a flat control, with no content area, that will be handled by the application.

For the most part of have this working, but now I would like to add a Click Event to the Control, adding it to the TabItem is working a treat, but is not ideal as I need a single place to run the same event.

The code should look like this

```
<MyTabControl Click="ClickEvent">
    <MyTabItem Header="One" />
    <MyTabItem Header="Two" />
</MyTabControl>
```

In the Code behind I have the Dependency set up like so.

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    static MyTabControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(asTabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTabControl)));

    }
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyTabControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click { add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); } remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); } }


    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        RaiseEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Now I know the OnMouseLeftButtonDown is not being fired, as the breakpoint I set here is not getting firing. So what I know is that the event is not being raised, which I am assuming it is not bubbling up from the MyTabItem.

So the question is, where do I go from here, to achieve what I am hoping to achieve.

Also, one more thing, because this is a flat control, with no content. I also have the need to make it behave with no default selection for a tab item.

The only solution I have managed to find is to create a dummy tab item. Which I would kind of like to avoid if possible.

```
<MyTabControl Click="ClickEvent">
    <MyTabItem Visibility="Hidden" />
    <MyTabItem Header="One" />
    <MyTabItem Header="Two" />
</MyTabControl>
```

I have been scouring the code for all the inherited controls, looking for a way to achieve both these issues, but either I am just purely blind or not understanding what I need to do. I know the selected tab, is defaulting to 0, which can be changed on the MyTabControl. But would rather not have to add that and have it controlled by the code somehow.

Any help in the right direction for both these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried setting selectedindex to -1 ?  and also how do you want a click event for tabitem? I am not getting what you want.

Comment: No I haven't tried setting the selectedIndex to -1, because I don't know where or how to do that in the code. As I said, I don't want to have to do this in the XAML. And as for the click event, I am not wanting it on the TabItem, I am wanting to handle it on the TabControl.

Comment: TabControl has SelectedIndex property.

Comment: Yes it does, but the only way to change that value is as a property in XAML.

Comment: You can use that property in C# (code behind) as well. I assume that you are new to wpf.

Comment: I am relatively new, every time I try to set that value in the custom control it tells me it doesn't exist. And I don't want to do it on the code behind to the page, because that is defeating the purpose of having it default to null and not zero.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share you custom control code here. Share whatever you done. It is becoming more confusing now.

Comment: The code is in the question, it is actually very simple requirement. The default SelectedIndex is set to zero, I need to have it set to null when the tabs / tabcontrol is created and do not want to have to do this via a property in XAML or code behind on the page.